# parallelize for loop and merge pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing

My script is as follows

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'],
                      'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3']})

def make_df(year):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'], str(year): [str(year), str(year+1), str(year+2), str(year+3)]})
    return df

for year in range(2020, 2015, -1):
        df = pd.merge(df, make_df(year), on=['key'], how='left')
```

The final df will be..

```
  key   A  2020  2019  2018  2017  2016
0  K0  A0  2020  2019  2018  2017  2016
1  K1  A1  2021  2020  2019  2018  2017
2  K2  A2  2022  2021  2020  2019  2018
3  K3  A3  2023  2022  2021  2020  2019
```

my actual `make_new_df(year)` is much more complex and takes too much time.

How can I paralleize the for-loop `for year in range(2020, 2015, -1):` and shorten processing time?

Comment: you can try to use standard modules `threading`, `multiprocessing` or external modules like `ray`, `joblib`, `pyspark` which may have some functions for `DataFrame`. Probably there is even module which name  I don't remeber - `pandas-???` - which can add multiprocessing to `DataFrame`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried some modules like multiprocessing or dask, but have failed to use them. I could not find any document which explains the detailed method to use them. All I have found were about multiprocessing in ONE dataframe but not about joining MULTIPLE dataframes into one. Any document you recommend?

Comment: you may generate new data in separated threads/processes but later you have to join them in main process.

Comment: other idea: maybe it would be faster to send data on [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) server, run code and download result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Edit: using `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`

After reading your comments it seems that you want to run your function in different processes (in parallel):

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'],
                      'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3']})
year_start = 2020
year_stop = 2015
year_range = range(year_start, year_stop, -1)

def make_df(year):
    df = pd.DataFrame({str(year): [str(year), str(year+1), str(year+2), str(year+3)]})
    return df

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(year_start - year_stop)
df_list = pool.map(func=make_df, iterable=year_range)
pool.close()
pool.join()

df = df.join(df_list)
print(df)
```

Comment: I don't know how your data actually looks like. You can still use `merge` with the key in a loop over `df_list`. It seemed unnecessary in your example since you always merged on the same column, so I initially replaced it with `join` (and removed the key column from the function)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your script works with some minor revisions regarding join. However, I don't know why, it doubles the time. Certainly, it uses more CPU(%) while running. There seems to be something peculiar in my code.

Comment: It must be because of the Python [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/). I've updated my answer to use `multiprocessing`. Let me know if you see any improvement!

Comment: Thank you Tranbi. There is an error when doing "pool=multiprocessing.Pool(year_start - year_stop)". I have been working on it but cannot find a solution. Is there anything   I miss?

Comment: Did you define`year_start` and `year_stop` like in my code? The first one has to be greater since it defines the size of the pool. Did you import the `multiprocessing` module?

Comment: Yes, I did them all. I think there seems a problem with the Windows python (or pycharm) regarding the permission issue since it says "PermissionError: [WinError 5]......".

Comment: There seems an unsolved Pycharm error, detailed here: [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36151?_ga=2.115097735.1008772079.1638117105-505598866.1636711445). Thank you, Tranbi, but I finally failed to solve the problem.....